# HOW TO FETCH A DIFFERENT POST IN EACH CARD IN PHP FROM DATABASE

Tags: php, html

Am having a problem with fetching posts from database. The posts are fecthed properly but each row has a different post. The posts are fetched vertically which is not what i want.

Here is my code;

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    require 'config.php';
            ?>

        <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM contents";
          $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
           //Check if there is data
            $check_data = mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0;

             if($check_data) {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

             ?>
    <section>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card mt-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $row['images'] ?>" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                            <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
                                <h3 class="card-desc"><?php echo $row['short_desc']; ?></h3>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>

               
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card mt-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $row['images'] ?>" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                            <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
                                <h3 class="card-desc"><?php echo $row['short_desc']; ?></h3>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
               
                
                
                
                
                    
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        
    

    <?php
            //To fetch the data into the correct places we will need to divide the php from while loop();

            

        }
    }
?>
</body>
    
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the output of the above code;

The posts tripple them selves according to the columns in the code but I would like to have a different post in every card in the same row
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    require 'config.php';
            ?>

        <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM contents";
          $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
           //Check if there is data
            $check_data = mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0;

             if($check_data) {
                $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)
             ?>
    <section>
    <div class="container">
          <?php
             $total_rows = count($rows) % 3 > 0 ? count($rows) % 3 + 1 : count($rows) / 3  ;
             $rows_counter = 0;
             $column_counter = 0;
             while($rows_counter<$total_rows) 
             {             
            ?>
            <div class="row">
               <?php for($i=0;$i<$rows_counter+1==$total_rows ? count($row)%3 ? 3;$i++) { 
                 $row = $rows[$colum_counter]
                 $column_counter++;
               ?>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card mt-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $row['images'] ?>" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                            <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
                                <h3 class="card-desc"><?php echo $row['short_desc']; ?></h3>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
             <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        
    

    <?php 
        }
      $rows_counter++;
    }
?>
</body>
    
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir for the answer its great but i still have one problem i would like to display a different post throughout the row like a diffeerent image lets  say for each card in the row from the database

Comment: edited answer by your comment